# I have installed anaconda for python 2.7 version, but not able to run python script which is importing pandas library from command prompt

Tags: python-2.7

I am able to use pandas from anaconda prompt, but when i am doing the same from windows command prompt ,its giving traceback like Importerror : no module named pandas.

I new to python,please help.

Comment: Please show your code in the question and not as images.

Comment: I have written a 1 line code to test if i can use pandas
import pandas as pd